# Inlineformset with crispy forms - display labels once only

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I have an inline formset being displayed with crispy forms. It works just fine, but I get the labels displayed above each row. I'd prefer them once, at the top of the table of fields, but not quite sure how to achieve this.

I have a layout object defined, where I've tried to turn off the labels to start with, but I guess helper objects don't work this way ...

```
class Formset(LayoutObject):
    template = "missions/formset.html"

    def __init__(self, formset_name_in_context, template=None):
        self.formset_name_in_context = formset_name_in_context
        self.fields = []
        if template:
            self.template = template

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK):
        formset = context[self.formset_name_in_context]
        return render_to_string(self.template, {"formset": formset})class Formset(LayoutObject):
    template = "missions/formset.html"
```

In the main form this is used as follows:

```
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                < snipped the main form parts as not relevant to the question >
                Div(
                    Fieldset(
                        _("Invitees"),
                        Field("allow_invitees_to_add_others", css_class="col-md-12"),
                        Formset("invitees"),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        )
```

And in my formset.html

```
<table>
    {{ formset.management_form|crispy }}
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <td>
            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
            {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

So I'd like to know:

1. How I can turn off the labels on each row in the formset.
2. How I can then loop over the lables in the template prior to the `{% for %}` loop so I only have to display them once.

**Edit:**
OK, so I've handled putting the top headers in, but still don't know how to turn off the headers for every form in the formset ...

```
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <th scope="col">
                {{ field.label }}
            </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after a whole load of messing around I finally sorted this out, though it's possible the label hiding is a little "hacky".

As I mentioned, the display of the header row can be handled in the template:

```
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <th scope="col">
                {{ field.label }}
            </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% endif %}
```

While turning off the labels can be done in the definition of the crispy forms layout object, and requires setting the helper on each form in the formset individually (it's this loop I worry may be a little hacky, but I will only have a handful of records here, so it should not be a massive performance overhead).

```
class Formset(LayoutObject):
    template = "missions/formset.html"

    def __init__(self, formset_name_in_context, template=None, hide_labels=True):
        self.formset_name_in_context = formset_name_in_context
        self.hide_labels = hide_labels
        self.fields = []
        if template:
            self.template = template

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK):
        formset = context[self.formset_name_in_context]
        if self.hide_labels:
            for form in formset:
                form.helper = FormHelper()
                form.helper.form_show_labels = False

        return render_to_string(self.template, {"formset": formset})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this where I was using an **inlineformset_factory** and formset helper to control the rendering.

I fixed the issue by overloading the **render_layout** method of the child FormHelper class and setting the *form_short_labels* context element to False for all but the first row based upon the suffix of the form prefix set by the formset.

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper


class CustomFormsetHelper(FormHelper):

    def render_layout(self, form, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK):
        """Hide the form labels after the first iteration"""
        context['form_show_labels'] = int(form.prefix.split("-")[-1]) == 0
        return super().render_layout(
            form=form, context=context, template_pack=template_pack
        )
```

The result was only the first form in the formset rendered with labels without any need to change the template